# XML to CSV Conversion with Xquery

Tags: csv, xquery, soa, osb

I need to convert below XML to CSV such that for null xml tag there must not be any comma in CSV file.

```
for example , consider below XML

<data>
<user>
<id>1</id>
<name>jaison</name>
<age>21</age>
</user>
<user>
<id>2</id>
<name>Monson</name>
<age></age>
</user>
</data>

expected csv:
id,name,age
1,jaison,21
2,Monson
```

Comment: Can you show the code you have currently (that outputs a comma)?

Comment: Also please add details about the XQuery version you use/your platform supports as XQuery 1.0 or XQuery 3.1 might allow different solutions.

Comment: `for $b in $req//ns1:topLevelArray
    return
    
      concat(escape-html-uri(string-join(($b/ns1:ID,
                                          $b/ns1:name,
                                          $b/ns1:PersonID,
                                          $b/ns1:age
                  
                                          )
                                           /normalize-space(),
                                        ",")
                             ),
             codepoints-to-string(10))
};`
My current code

Comment: I am using Xquery 1.0

Comment: output I get for the above code: **77,Kevin,,67,David,20**

Answer (score 1):

One way would be to try to add a `[normalize-space()]` predicate to all element selections e.g.

```
for $b in $req//ns1:topLevelArray     
return            
  concat(escape-html-uri(
   string-join(($b/ns1:ID[normalize-space()],                                           
                $b/ns1:name[normalize-space()],                                           
                $b/ns1:PersonID[normalize-space()],                                           
                $b/ns1:age[normalize-space()]                                                              
               )/normalize-space(),                                         
               ",") 
    ), codepoints-to-string(10)) }
```